# Proper way to pass variables through chain of components in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to improve my code style, so there is a question: what is right way to pass data through chain of parent-child components?
For example: i have a CategoryView component. It is receiving prop:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Some title",
  "articles": [(array of article objects..)]
}
```

Inside of CategoryView i have an ArticleEditDialog component. When i'm editing some article, clearly i need to pass there object of article, which will be a reference. But when i'm creating a new article, i need somehow push new article in array of articles. So, i need to pass in article edit dialog array of articles. But then, i'm facing that i need to know category id when creating new article, so now i need to pass to article edit dialog complete category object. When adding some sub-components, this chain of passing root object may be long. Is it right or there is a more proper way? Maybe you can advice some articles about it?

Comment: For better and more simple state management I suggest to use #pinia
https://pinia.vuejs.org

Comment: @emy thank you, tried this and it way more simple than vuex and made everything really easier!

Comment: You may not need even Pinia - just try [Vue.observable](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable)

Comment: @IVOGELOV It's for Vue 2, it was completely replaced with composition api which has being used for quite a long time

Comment: @EstusFlask The Composition API in Vue 3 can use the same trick with [reactive](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive) - again without Pinia.